# DDR threshold levels and timing constraints

Tags: signal-integrity

I am new in field of DDR and high speed memories, i come across SSTL signaling level diagram, over there VIH & VIL are defined as both DC and AC. What is the difference between them, what is the significance of this? Is timing constraint is related to it? is high speed switching related to it? 
Thanks in advance for you help.

[image]

Comment: The datasheets from Micron (which is what this looks like) are extremely detailed. What part of the datasheet information are you having trouble with?

Comment: This is not from datasheet , it is from application note AN2582 from freescale. It just mentioned over there and they havent defiend what is AC & DC parameters? Is it something related to biasing or small signal analysis?

Comment: Related to your deleted "How to do voltage shifting of a RETURN TO ZERO signal?" question. PLEASE do no delete questions when people have started to put effort into helping you. ALL we need is for you to make your question clear and we can very probably help. You want output as 4 levels (+/-2, +/- 14 BUT R1 has only 3 levels - so cannot be directly translated. - a diagram of what you want would be extremely helpful.